# Python ternary execution order

Tags: python

In python, if I use a ternary operator:

```
x = a if <condition> else b
```

Is `a` executed even if `condition` is false? Or does `condition` evaluate first and then goes to either `a` or `b` depending on the result?

Comment: Well, why not try it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The condition is evaluated first, if it is False, `a` is not evaluated: [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Answer (score 4):

It gets evaluated depending if meets the condition. For example:

```
condition = True
print(2 if condition else 1/0)
#Output is 2

print((1/0, 2)[condition])
#ZeroDivisionError is raised
```

No matter if `1/0` raise an error, is never evaluated as the condition was True on the evaluation.

Sames happen in the other way:

```
condition = False
print(1/0 if condition else 2)
#Output is 2
```

Comment: "in order" is too vague. It's not left to right, which is how I'd normally understand your statement.

Comment: Agree, changing it